# How do I tag a react app on clients site?

Tags: reactjs, analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have a basic 6 question React Quiz App. My goal is to launch this App on a client's website. I want to add analytics tagging to record performance and engagement:

0. user views on questions and flow
1. user interactions clicks
2. user choices based on form inputs
3. user quiz results/completion conversion
4. other misc user data

With this app being loaded externally through clients tag manager, what would be the best approach/analytics service to track this data? Any services you guys recommend?

Thanks!